# Updating a collection inside array of collections in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection `workspaces` in my MongoDB which consist of records that looks like as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bdc4a13504f5ed743ad025"),
    "name" : "My workspace",
    "user_id" : ObjectId("58b6cf53988a874af070fd3b"),
    "uploads" : [ 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.tif"
        }, 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0134.png"
        }, 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.png"
        }, 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0134.tif"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my objective is that i want to append something in one of record of array  `uploads` with the match criteria of `original` field value. For example i want to append `"pseg" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.pseg.tif"` to the `{"original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.tif"}` collection in following way:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58bdc4a13504f5ed743ad025"),
    "name" : "Objective",
    "user_id" : ObjectId("58b6cf53988a874af070fd3b"),
    "uploads" : [ 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.tif",
            "pseg" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.pseg.tif"
        }, 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0134.png"
        }, 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.png"
        }, 
        {
            "original" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0134.tif"
        }
    ]
}
```

i tried using `$elemMatch` and then i added `$addToSet` in following way:

```
db.getCollection('workspaces').update({"_id": ObjectId("58bdc4a13504f5ed743ad025"),"uploads": {$elemMatch: {"original": "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.tif"}}},{$addToSet:{"uploads.$": {"pseg" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.pseg.tif"}}})
```

but it gives me following error:

```
Cannot apply $addToSet to a non-array field. Field named '0' has a non-array type object in the document _id: ObjectId('58bdc4a13504f5ed743ad025')
```

I think i crafted the query wrong can anyone tell me what is wrong and how can i solve it?

Sorry for my bad english :) hope you understood what i said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax. You have to use `$set` with `postional` operator to reach the element.

```
db.getCollection('workspaces').update(
{"_id": ObjectId("58bdc4a13504f5ed743ad025"),"uploads": {$elemMatch: {"original": "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.tif"}}},
{$set:{"uploads.$.pseg" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.pseg.tif"}})
```

More information here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array

You can simplify your query criteria. You don't need to use `$elemMatch` operator for single query condition. You can use dot notation.

```
db.getCollection('workspaces').update(
{"_id": ObjectId("58bdc4a13504f5ed743ad025"),"uploads.original": "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.tif"},
{$set:{"uploads.$.pseg" : "DE-20__450_GG_5002_N23_994__0136.pseg.tif"}})
```

More information here 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. Much appreciated for the link its really helpful in making sense of correct syntax. Also thanks for giving dot notation idea i didn't know that we can use it in the case of arrays of collection too.